# What does "I have been sick" imply?

Tags: sentence-meaning, present-perfect, time

If I say that *"I have been sick since Tuesday"* That would mean that my sickness started from Tuesday and I am still sick.

But if I just say: *"I have been sick"* without a duration or time expression, can it mean more than one thing depending on context?

E.g. Could it mean *"I'm still sick"* or *"I was sick"* depending on context?

In my opinion it should just mean that *"my sickness has just recently ended"* since it is present perfect tense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By itself "I have been sick" doesn't say much about your current condition.  Depending on the context, it can imply that you are healthy now, or that you're still sick.

> I'm in bed.  I've been sick all week (I'm still sick)
>
> I'm so glad I'm feeling better.  I've been sick all week.  (I'm OK now).

It is often given as an excuse for not doing something,

> I haven't been to work at all this week -- I've been sick
>
> I'm sorry I missed your party, but I've been sick.

However in both cases it's not clear whether I'm sick *now*.  You would need more information to judge.  Of course you can always just ask:

> You've been sick?  How are you feeling now?

Comment: So, that in context can I also say _"I am so glad I am feeling better. I have been sick since Tuesday."_ which would mean that I am not sick anymore? But if I just say _"I have been sick since Tuesday"_ that would mean that I am still sick.

Comment: No, I mean that the phrase tells you nothing about whether the person is still sick.  That you get from context, or you have to ask.

Comment: Right, what about my examples in comment. Do they stand correct as well if I use "since"?

Comment: "Since" *sort of* implies that you are still sick, but unless I could tell by looking at you, I might still ask.

Answer (score -1):

"I have been sick" describes the physical act of vomiting. "I am sick" describes a general feeling of being unwell.

Comment: That might be true in some contexts, but what about in general? Can you [edit] your post to address OP’s specific concerns?